# jquery, js. custom text color

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i change the color of the text inside input box to different color. eg. text to green, red, purple etc.. I planned to use select box to store the different color and based on the selected color change the "text" color: but I am having hard time implementing into code. I am new to js, jquery any help will be greatly appreciated. Also what needs to be done to get  the text with selected color to a table(do i save the color in databse?). I will be very thankful to get any help on this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small demo based on your requirements. You can read the comments in the code.

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  function get(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id); // Return the element given an id.
  }

  var selColors = get("selColors"); // Store the context of the selColors element.
  var txtMyText = get("txtMyText"); // Store the context of the txtMyText element.
  var myForm = get("myForm"); // Store the context of the myForm element.
  var selectedColor = get("selectedColor");

  // This is an object that has 2 properties: (color and value). These properties can hold in it string values.
  var obj = {
    color: "",
    value: ""
  };

  // When you select an option.
  selColors.onchange = function() {
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
      obj.color = this.value; // this.value contains the color that you have selected.
      selectedColor.setAttribute("style", "background-color: " + obj.color);
      txtMyText.setAttribute("style", "color: " + this.value); // With this you can set a style to the txtMyText textbox.
    }

  };

  // When you submit the form.
  myForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
    obj.value = txtMyText.value;
    console.log(obj); // Shows in the console the object with the current color and value of your textbox.
    e.preventDefault();
  };
})();
```

```css
#myForm {
  border: solid 1px #335a82;
}

#myForm fieldset {
  border: solid 1px #a3c9d4;
}

#myForm fieldset div {
  margin: 5px;
}

#myForm fieldset div label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
}

#selectedColor {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Configuration</legend>
    <div>
      <label>Colors:</label>
      <select id="selColors">
    <option value="">[Select a color]</option>
      <option value="#5069b1">#5069b1</option>
      <option value="#ff0000">#ff0000</option>
      <option value="#841b72">#841b72</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <label>Selected color:</label>
    <div id="selectedColor">
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Preview</legend>
    <div>
      <label>Text:</label>
      <input id="txtMyText" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Danny  this is tooooooooo awesome.Thanks for a great help! One small question I am getting values from db and printing it to the div/table, how can i get text with the selected color in my div?(meaning if i choose my text to be red and hit submit I have to see red color text in my div/table)

Comment: Please, could you update your question with the related html **div/table** that you have?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myinput').css("color","#fdd");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test" id="myinput">
```

You could try this also:

```js
$('#myinput').css('color',$('#myinput').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="#04edee" id="myinput" onkeyup="$('#myinput').css('color',$('#myinput').val());">
```

Comment: currently i  am seeing only one color("#fdd"), how can i have ability to select different color?

Answer (score 0):

You could use js to select the class or id of the `<input class=".." id=".."`>
Then you would be able to change the `CSS` attributes with js.

See the following example

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" class="input1">
</form>
```

So your `<input>` class is input1. Using the following `CSS` code you could select a `class` by its name. See the example below

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
}
</script>
```

Now by adding a `CSS` atribute like `color` to the function you could change the existing or add a new `CSS` rule to your `<input>` field.

I think you could get pretty far with this example.
Let me know if it helps!

Comment: so do I save different color in css file?

Comment: No you don't. You'll only use one color in the css file. but you're able to switch them around using js.

Comment: I am sorry i am new to js, jquery. can you please post how to switch color using js?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery option to show some fun stuff:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myColors').on('change', function() {
    var picked = $(this).val();
    $('#currentcolor').css("background-color", picked);
    $('#results').append("<div>" + $(this).find("option:selected").text() + "|" + picked + "</div>");
  });
  // verbose add on click of button
  $('#addHot').on('click', function() {
    var valHot = '#69b4ff';
    var newName = "Hot Pink Triadic Blue";
    //$('#myColors').append("<option value='"+valHot+" style='color:"+nameHot+"'>"+nameHot+"</option>");
    var newOpt = $("<option></option>");
    newOpt.css("color:" + valHot);
    newOpt.prop("value", valHot);
    newOpt.text(newName);
    newOpt.appendTo('#myColors');
    console.log(newOpt);
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="myColors">
    <option value="red" style="color:red">Red</option>
    <option value="green" style="color:green">Green</option>
    <option value="cyan" style="color:cyan">Cyan</option>
    <option value="#0080ff" style="color:#0080ff">Analogous Cyan</option>
  </select>
  <button id="addHot" type="button">
    Add Hot Pink Triadic Blue
  </button>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="currentcolor">
    current color is background
  </div>
  <div id="results">
    Show stuff:
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I hit submit and losing the color of text in my table, the form is submitting values to the DB, do I need to save the selected  color in db to retain the color of the text?

Comment: Two parts here - one is to present some color, there are a LOT of potential colors, you either need a SET of them or a way to present ALL the colors.  Plenty of information on color pickers on that available.  Now to have that get saved you need to store any "name" for your color and/or the color as in the example I presented.  Saving a color is really no different than saving any other value an plenty of examples on that available as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do create class for every color like .green .purple and just remove and add classes

```
$(".input1").addClass("red").removeClass("green");
```

and you can also add remore these classes with selected box color change

Comment: Now I can successfully color  my text but when i submit my form the text loses its background color?how can I retain the color of the text.